# how to create full-text index on column with no errors

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Hello i'm building database using Visual Studio 2015
but there is some errors interrupt my work

here is my table query:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Post] (
    [Id]            INT        NOT NULL,
    [job_desc]  NTEXT       NOT NULL,
    [UID]           INT        NOT NULL,
    [TheWork]       NVARCHAR(50)        NOT NULL,
    [Photo_Of_Work_1] NCHAR (50) DEFAULT ('W_No_Pho') NULL,
    [Photo_Of_Work_2] NCHAR (50) DEFAULT ('W_No_Pho') NULL,
    [Photo_Of_Work_3] NCHAR (50) DEFAULT ('W_No_Pho') NULL,

    [DT]            DATETIME   NOT NULL,
    [Salary] MONEY NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Post_ToPerson] FOREIGN KEY ([UID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Person] ([Id])
);
```

so i have `job_desc` column which type is `ntext` so i can't use normal index on it so i have to use `full-text-index`

and i have this code here:

```
 GO
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX jdui  ON [Post] ([job_desc]);
    GO
    CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ftc AS DEFAULT;
    GO
    CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[Post] ([Job_Desc]) KEY INDEX jdui ON ftc WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO
```

but i don't really know why an error occurs every time i update,
and this is the error syntax:

> Message SQL00000 Creating [dbo].[Post].[jdui]... Error SQL72014 .Net
>   SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 1919, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column
>   'job_desc' in table 'dbo.Post' is of a type that is invalid for use as
>   a key column in an index. Error SQL72045 Script execution error.  The
>   executed script: CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [jdui]
>       ON [dbo].[Post]([job_desc] ASC);
>
> Message SQL00000 An error occurred while the batch was being executed.

so anyone can help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design SQL server does not allow any indexes on the column types such as `nText` , `Text` , `varchar(max)` or `nVarchar(max)`.

Here you are trying to create a Unique constraint on the column `job_desc` which is of `NTEXT` type hence the error.

Now you might ask well sql server doesn't allow any indexes but you are trying to create a unique constraint, as a matter of fact when we create a unique constraint on a column, behind the scenes SQL server creates a `Unique non-Clustered` index to enforce uniqueness on that column. hence the error message.

**Solution**

Change the type of column to something that you can create index on like `Varchar(8000)` or maybe `nVarchar(4000)` .

Or choose an alternate column to create index on. Maybe the `Id` column.

Comment: which is better/faster full-text-index or normal index with query :
`select job_desc from post where job_desc like %the best%`
example: let it be **sql server is the best** if i want to search for every
 **the best** word in this column

Comment: You have to have  a unique key on any of the columns in the table, not necessarily on the column you want to create full-text index, This key is used by the full-text to do lookups in the table. You can create the unique index on the ID column and have the FT on any column that has a index compatible data type.

Comment: i tried this:
`GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX jid  ON [Post] ([Id]);
GO
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ftc AS DEFAULT;
GO
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[Post] ([job_desc]) KEY INDEX jid ON ftc WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO
`